# Perl: Sort values in multidimensional hash

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine that looks likes this:

```
...

sub UserLogins { 
  my %loginData; 
  my @logins = qx(last) or die;

  foreach my $row (@logins) {
    if ( $row=~ /^(\w+)\s+/ and (("$1" ne "reboot") and ("$1" ne "wtmp")) ) {
      $loginData{$1}{"logins"}++; 
    }
  }

return \%loginData
}

...
```

Using this subroutine in main script, I get following output:

```
...

$VAR1 = {
     'user1' => {
             'oldpassword' = 0,
             'filesize' => '14360',
             'logins' => 1
      },
      'user2' => {
             'oldpassword' = 0,
             'filesize' => '1220',
             'logins' => 15
      },
      'user3' => {
             'oldpassword' = 1,
             'filesize' => '1780',
             'logins' => 7
      }
}

...
```

I wonder how I should sort my `%loginData` hash so user with largest number of logins gets printed first (in this case user2, user3, user1).

I have also tried to sort values in this way:

```
foreach my $test_sort (sort {$a <=> $b} values %loginData) {
    say $test_sort;
}
```

But this function doesn't work at all.

Another thing I tried and didn't work:

```
print "$_\n" foreach sort {$loginData{$b}->{logins} <=> $loginData{$a}->{logins}} keys %loginData;
```

**Update**

This function actually works, but shows errors massages:

```
print "$_\n" foreach sort {$userData{$b}->{'logins'} <=> $userData{$a}->{'logins'}} keys %userData;
```

Errors:

```
Use of uninitialized values in numeric comparison (<=>)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried anything so far. How do you think you should go about it?

Comment: I have tried to use `my ($UsersToCheck) = shift @_;
    inituserlogins() unless %loginData;
    return $loginData{$UsersToCheck} ? $loginData{$UsersToCheck} : 0;` but in this case I have to pass usernames to script, which is not allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort hash keys of nested hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782038/sort-hash-keys-of-nested-hash)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a canonical solution for accessing elements of a hash in some order based on an attribute of the value (in this case `logins`):

```
for (sort { $loginData{$b}->{logins} <=>  $loginData{$a}->{logins} } keys %loginData)
{
    ... 
}
```

Note reversal of `$b` and `$a` to achieve a reverse sort (most logins first).

Comment: Your answer is correct IMHO, just one nitpick: DataDumper called the array $VAR1 - maybe better to refer to the hash as %loginData

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort a hash. From the Perl docs:

> Hash entries are returned in an apparently random order.

You can, compute a list of keys that index the hash in the order you like.

Something like this:

```
use Data::Dumper;

our $hash = {
     'user1' => {
             'oldpassword' => 0,
             'filesize' => '14360',
             'logins' => 1
      },
      'user2' => {
             'oldpassword' => 0,
             'filesize' => '1220',
             'logins' => 15
      },
      'user3' => {
             'oldpassword' => 1,
             'filesize' => '1780',
             'logins' => 7
      }
};

sub KeysByLogins {
  my $hash = shift;
  map { $_->[1] }
  sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
  map { [ $hash->{$_}->{logins}, $_ ] } keys %$hash;
}

foreach my $key (KeysByLogins($hash)) {
  print Data::Dumper->Dump([$hash->{$key}], [$key]) . "\n";
}
```

Then...

```
$ perl foo.pl
```

```
$user1 = {
           'filesize' => '14360',
           'oldpassword' => 0,
           'logins' => 1
         };

$user3 = {
           'logins' => 7,
           'oldpassword' => 1,
           'filesize' => '1780'
         };

$user2 = {
           'oldpassword' => 0,
           'filesize' => '1220',
           'logins' => 15
         };
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you provide any example of what you are saying?

Comment: `map { [ $hash{$_}->{logins}, $_ ] }` should be `map { [ $hash->{$_}{logins}, $_ ] }`

Comment: Where does my $hash get values from? Can't fit into my script due errors.

Comment: @ChrisCharley That's an optional shorthand, I believe. It runs fine as-is in my Perl.

Comment: @MagomedSegaIsmailov You really need to do more learning about the Perl language.  See the complete code above.

Comment: Odd. When run under `use strict`, it won't compile with msg. _Global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name at t33.pl line 29
Execution of t33.pl aborted due to compilation errors._. Wonder why it works ok without strict. I think it should not recognize `%hash` even when not run under `strict`.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Sorry there was a missing `->`.  Ought to be okay now. Not sure why it worked at all. Perl is a beast.

Comment: Yes Gene, I was working with it today to try to understand the behavior.